# Select Users by Department and get their security groups / filter output Powershell

Tags: powershell

``
Hi,

I’m new to PowerShell so guidance would be very much appreciated.
I’ve been trying to create a security group report based of Departments.
The idea is that I can use a department variable e.g ‘Accounts’ and filter the specific users.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { department -eq $Department -and enabled -eq $true }
```

The above works great
From there I get all the users security groups but I’m also trying to exclude certain groups from the final output. Now I tried to add filters and exclude before they passed into my foreach but I can’t get anything to work.

```
Clear-Host
$Department = 'Accounts'

#Get Users from Department Variable
$UsersTable = Get-ADUser -Filter { department -eq $Department -and enabled -eq $true } | Select-Object sAMAccountName 

foreach ($user in $UsersTable) {
    
  #Get Group
  $Group = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership  $user.sAMAccountName  | Select-Object name,groupscope
  
  Foreach ($G in $Group) {

    $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
    
      'Name' = $user.sAMAccountName
      'SG_Name' = $g.name
      'Scope'  = $g.groupScope
    }

    $table.Add($obj)
  }
}
```

I’m probably going about this entirely the wrong way.
Departments-> Users -> Groups / Group Membership -> Exclude Certain Groups -> Output
I also wondered if I was using the correct Group cmdlet.

I tried filtering on Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What groups are you trying to exclude? have you got an exmaple of that code

Comment: Check the results of the Groups by using : $Group | Format-Table.

Comment: @Rooster: Whatever group you are trying to exclude that can be put together in a `if` condition and can be excluded. But for that to happen. kindly share us the group names and whats your are getting currently.

Comment: So as an example which work with Get-AdGroup and my filtering:
`Get-ADGroup -filter { (name -like "*SG*") -or (name -like "*Dept*") -or (name -like "*Department*") -or (name -like "*GG*") -and (name -ne 'Domain Admins') }`

Comment: Why not filter using a `Where-Object` clause: `$Group = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership  $user.sAMAccountName | ? {$_.Name -Match 'SG|Dept|GG' -and $_.Name -notmatch 'Domain Admins'}`.